# how does heterogeneous servers fit in Clos topology?

Tags: design

I wonder whether heterogeneous servers can fit together in Clos / spine-leaf topology? And how the design should look like in this case?  We have 600 10G stand-alone servers and want multiple 40G uplinks to the spine and 300 1G servers and want multiple 10G uplinks to the spine.

Comment: You'd need to provide a whole lot more information for us to consider (current topology, current problems, bottlenecks, workload profiles, your overall aim and concept). Also, opinion-oriented questions and host configurations are explicitly off-topic here, see the [help]. Additionally, I fail to see where heterogeneous servers, Clos and spine-leaf are connected (or clash). [This question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/61128/regarding-ciscos-hierarchical-network-design) might provide some help already.

Comment: I am new to the topic; I have spent a couple of days reading through spine-leaf topology.  All designs assume that the servers are homogeneous, same downlink, and same uplink requirements.

It's a new data center, so there is no current topology in place yet. We expect to have up to 48 Racks of Servers, with 15-20 servers per rack dual-homed to both ToR switches.

Comment: So you actually mean *asymmetric loads*. I understand hetereogeneous servers as a bunched collection of Windows, LAMP, Mac, ... Even more so, you need to give us a *much* better picture of what the challenges are. You need to consider north-south and east-west traffic separately. Sizing and renting the appropriate bandwidth can't be all.

Comment: Inside a datacenter you should consider a hierarchical approach (without asymmetry) like what I linked to.